# Remove line in openGLes android

Tags: android, opengl-es, line

I'm writing a program that draws lines. Code:

```
public class Lines {
public static final int Red = 0;
public static final int Green = 1;
public static final int Cyan = 2;
public static final int Magenta = 3;
public static final int Yellow = 4;
public static final int Black = 5;
public static final int White = 6;

private static final float[] RED = new float[] { 1f, 0f, 0f };
private static final float[] GREEN = new float[] { 0f, 1f, 0f };
private static final float[] CYAN = new float[] { 0f, 1f, 1f };
private static final float[] MAGENTA = new float[] { 1f, 0f, 1f };
private static final float[] YELLOW = new float[] { 1f, 1f, 0f };
private static final float[] BLACK = new float[] { 0f, 0f, 0f };
private static final float[] WHITE = new float[] { 1f, 1f, 1f };
private static final float[][] COLOR = new float[][] { RED, GREEN, CYAN, MAGENTA, YELLOW, BLACK, WHITE };

private float[][] points;
private FloatBuffer[] vertexBuffer;

public Lines() {
    points = new float[7][];
    for (int i=0;i<7;i++) {
        points[i] = new float[] {};
    }
    vertexBuffer = new FloatBuffer[7];
}

public void addLine(int color, PointF a, PointF b) {
    float[] new_points = new float[] { a.x, a.y, b.x, b.y };

    float[] temp = new float[points[color].length+new_points.length];
    System.arraycopy(points[color],0,temp,0,points[color].length);
    System.arraycopy(new_points,0,temp,points[color].length,4);
    points[color] = temp;

    ByteBuffer vertexByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(points[color].length * 4);
    vertexByteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    vertexBuffer[color] = vertexByteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();
    vertexBuffer[color].put(points[color]);
    vertexBuffer[color].position(0);
}

public void draw(GL10 gl) {
    for (int i=0;i<7;i++) {
        if (vertexBuffer[i] == null) continue;
        gl.glColor4f(COLOR[i][0], COLOR[i][1], COLOR[i][2], 1f);
        gl.glVertexPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer[i]);
        gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_LINES, 0, points[i].length/2);
    }
}
```

and

```
    public void setColor(int color) {
    this.color = color;
}

public void raise() {
    down = false;
}

public void putDown() {
    down = true;
}

public void move(float length) {
    float radians = (float)Math.toRadians(degree);
    float x_mul = (float)Math.sin(radians);
    float y_mul = (float)Math.cos(radians);
    PointF pf = new PointF(x_mul*length,y_mul*length);
    if (down) {
        lines.addLine(color, position, new PointF(position.x + pf.x, position.y + pf.y));
    }
    position.x += pf.x;
    position.y += pf.y;
}
```

When i draw a single line, everything is fine. When i draw a white line in the same place, everything is fine too. But when i draw another color line (for example red, in the same place), it does not work.

Anyone has an idea how to solve the problem?

Comment: Please rephrase your question as it is impossible to understand what you want and what is your current result. The last drawn line IS on top and as it seems from your code that would be the white line. So is that the issue or the expected result you are not seeing but should?

Comment: I corrected. I hope now is possible to understand.